# Remove pdf bookmarks programmatically from outline using iTextSharp VS2017 c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have pdf files where I need to remove bookmarks based on if the bookmark contains "Blank Page" or "Type = Plain" as the text/value of the bookmark.

I can read them [bookmarks] from the  files using the "How to read PDF bookmarks programmatically" question.

The bookmark I want is the first bookmark of each group of pages and it has a child that I need to keep in place as well.

Once that is done, I can process the files as I need since they will then only have the bookmark for each group of pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your bookmarks to a enumerable that you can do things with, do:

`IList<Dictionary<string, object>> list = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);`

You should be able to just remove the ones that you don't want using some linq:

`Where(x => x.Key != "Type = Plain" && x.Key != "Blank Page")`

Don't forget to iterate over each dictionary in the `IList` and rebuild a new IList object to be passed back into the stamper like so:
`stamper.setOutlines(result);`